# C# BitConverter problems

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter

Normaly if you want for example represent 5 in byte array it will be smth like {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05} but BitConverter gives me reversed array({0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00})
Why it is so and where I'm wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx  Big vs little endian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odds are that you are on a little-endian architecture (which is the case for the common x86 and x86-64 architectures). You can verify this with the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property. 
On such an architecture, the *least* significant *byte* comes first, which explains why

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(5)
```

produces

```
{ 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

You could of course reverse the array if required based on the system/target endianness. You can find such an `EndianBitConverter` listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/iso-parser/source/browse/trunk/EndianBitConverter.cs).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following wrapper classes to handle the case of the `BitConverter` expecting Little Endien.

```
    public static Int16 ToInt16(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset);
    }

    public static Int32 ToInt32(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset);
    }

    public static Int64 ToInt64(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(8).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(data, offset);
    }
```

Comment: if condition duplicated in ternary operator